Slurm mutli-node uses one node
When setting the value of n (ntasks-per-node) to any value aside from 1, it assigns tasks to only one node and ignores the other nodes. Any idea why?
#SBATCH --job-name=pytorch-multinode
#SBATCH --output=/home/output/%j%x.out # output log file
#SBATCH --error=/home/error/%j%x.err  # error file
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00  # 24 hour of wall time
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --partition=gpu  # GPU partition
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:4
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=n
#SBATCH --export=ALL

I tried searching for an explanation in the documentation but couldn't find why this happens. I was trying to train on multiple nodes.

The relevant code is missing. SLURM only allocates the resources that you requested. It is you the one that assigns the actual tasks to the nodes given. And in your snipped, you don't show how you do that. You are probably assigning all the tasks to the same node, as you are explaining. You should distribute the tasks as told to SLURM.
